# HTML5 Canvas Image Move Left Right Up Down with Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to create an online image editor using HTML5 and getting issue while perform image move with buttons. It does the move with mouse drag but couldn't fix it for buttons. I want to make it work with Move Up, Move Down, Move Right, Move Left Buttons.

```
jQuery('#moveUp').click(function () {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    var x = rect.left;
    var y = rect.top + 1;

    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
});
```

Here is my current program.
 [Fiddle Project](https://jsfiddle.net/74u2ka1m/1/)

Comment: What you are asking for is: How to handle keyboard key press with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `image` instead of `canvas`.

```
jQuery('#moveUp').click(function () {
var rect = image.getBoundingClientRect();
var x = rect.left;
var y = rect.top - 1;
clear();
element.translate(x, y);
drawImage();
});
```

...or if you prefer a function in order to not having to repeat yourself:

```
function move(direction) {
  var rect = image.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = rect.left;
  var y = rect.top;
  var dist = 5 //set distance

  switch (direction) {
    case 'up':
        y -= dist;
      break;
    case 'down':
        y += dist;
      break; 
    case 'left':
        x -= dist;
      break;
    case 'right':
        x += dist;
      break; 
  };

  clear();
    element.translate(x, y);
  drawImage();
};

jQuery('#moveUp').click(function () {
    move('up');
});


jQuery('#moveDown').click(function () {
    move('down');
});

jQuery('#moveLeft').click(function () {
    move('left');
});

jQuery('#moveRight').click(function () {
    move('right');
});
```

Regarding keys, check this one out: https://api.jquery.com/keypress/ - example (if you decide to use the function I created above):

```
$(document).keydown(function () {
     move('down');
});
```